# How to show the element using z index

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have created a simple div and svg..

```css
#firstElement {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
  left: 55px;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: -1;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  pointer-events: all;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id='firstElement'></div>
  <svg>
  <rect id="border" y="0" x="0" height="100" width="200" opacity="1" fill="white" stroke="#DDDDDD" stroke-width="0"></rect>
  <circle id="circle" cx="100" cy="50" r="40" fill="lime" />
</svg>
</div>
```

The firstElement(ID) is not visible even if I set the `z-index`.

My expected output is, `border` -> `firstElement` -> `circle`

[image]

how to acheive this?

Comment: I am sorry, I can't exactly understand what you are trying to achieve, can you provide a sample picture as well? Setting the "z-index: -1" will cause it to have lower z-index than all the other elements so it will just not be visible.

Comment: and it is already absolutely positioned.

Comment: @SamuilPetrov i have updated

Comment: @jai yes positioned but any possible to change? using zindex or something like that?

Answer (score 2):

Solution: Remove the `<rect>` tag inside the `<svg>`.

Issue: The problem is in your `<svg>` you are applying a rectangle (`<rect>`) around the `<circle>` which is has `height="100"` `width="200"` and `fill="white"`. If you simply change `opacity="0"`, then the `#firstElement` div becomes visible behind the circle. I am not sure why you have included that `<rect>` in the first place.

The whole `<svg>` tag is one single unit, so the elements in it have the same `z-index`. You cannot insert a `<div>` in between the elements of an `<svg>` by using `z-index`. You will have to split the `<svg>` elements into two for that.

```css
#firstElement {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 57px;
  top: 10px;
  z-index: -1;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  pointer-events: all;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id='firstElement'></div>
  <svg>
  <!-- <rect id="border" y="0" x="0" height="100" width="200" opacity="0" fill="white" stroke="#DDDDDD" stroke-width="0"></rect> -->
  <circle id="circle" cx="100" cy="50" r="40" fill="lime" />
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: if the rect color is pink how it's working? it should be shown as pink(rect)-red(div)-green(circle) changing the opacity is not correct

Comment: @AkbarBasha Why should the `rect` be pink??

Comment: @WasteD OP means that reducing the `opacity` of the `<rect>` makes it invisible, rendering it useless when OP change the `fill` attribute to other color

Comment: By changing the opactiy, you are actually removing the rectangle, it is as good as deleting the whole `<rect>` tag. Now this actually meets your expected OP. You had not even mentioned a pink rectangle. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I just shown as example.. the firstElement(div) is customer respective element... this was given from user like annotation.

Comment: The whole `<svg>` tag is one single unit, so the elements in it have the same `z-index`. In short you cannot insert a `<div>` in between the elements of an `<svg>` by using `z-index`. You will have to split the `<svg>` into two for that. See the answer by Zsolt.

Answer (score 2):

You can move your `firstElement` into `svg` using `foreignObject`

```css
#firstElement {
  background-color:red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
}
svg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width:2px;
    pointer-events: all;
}
```

```html
<div>
<svg>
  <rect id="border" y="0" x="0" height="100" width="200" opacity="1" fill="white" stroke="#DDDDDD" stroke-width="0"></rect>
  <foreignObject x="50" y="10">
    <div id="firstElement"></div>
  </foreignObject>
  <circle id="circle" cx="100" cy="50" r="40" fill="lime"></circle>
</svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add any thing except SVG code.

```html
<svg>
  <rect id="border" y="0" x="0" height="150" width="200" opacity="1" fill="white" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1"></rect>
  <rect id="border" y="25" x="50" height="100" width="100" opacity="1" fill="red" stroke="#DDDDDD" stroke-width="0"></rect>
  <circle id="circle" cx="100" cy="75" r="40" fill="lime" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the drawings in different svg tags, position svg's absolute, give them z-indexes.

```css
#firstElement {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
  left: 55px;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: all;
}
#svgRect {
  z-index:0;
}
#svgCircle {
 z-index:2;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id='firstElement'></div>
  <svg id="svgRect">
  <rect id="border" y="0" x="0" height="100" width="200" opacity="1" fill="white" stroke="#DDDDDD" stroke-width="0"></rect>
</svg>
<svg id="svgCircle">
  <circle id="circle" cx="100" cy="50" r="40" fill="lime" />
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: firstElement is always div there is no option to change that

Comment: @AkbarBasha Its still a div, I just put the border and circle in separate svg tags

Comment: yes but that one is given from customer... that one is always div

Comment: @AkbarBasha Sorry, I don't really understand your concern. Can you please elaborate it?